# Choropleth map from voronoi map from a set of coordinates (d3+leaflet)

Tags: leaflet, d3, voronoi-thiessen, choropleth

I have a csv file with a set of coordinates with the following structure:
`id,name,latitude,longitude`
(24 values).

Those 24 points represent coordinates in a city. I would like to get **a voronoi map** with those coordinates as centroids, and **then colour the polygons as if it were a choropleth map**. The result of this will be a map to be published on a web dashboard, so I will be using js-only frameworks.

I've been following [this](https://chriszetter.com/blog/2014/06/15/building-a-voronoi-map-with-d3-and-leaflet/) tutorial and [this](http://bl.ocks.org/shimizu/925bd1a92b63753608ef) example (leaflet+voronoi), but it's hard to find:

1. Tutorials with current/modern versions of d3 and/or leaflet.
2. Tutorials or articles on how to do the mapping process I need (coordinates>voronoi>choropleth).

Currently I am following the [d3.voronoi](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#voronoi-diagrams-d3-voronoi) section in the d3 API docs in order to understand how to generate the regions/polygons, but I don't know how to process those in order to generate the choropleth map using leaflet and mapbox.

Comment: Have you managed to make anything work? If so, can you share a link? I want to do the same thing but running into the same problems you are.

Comment: I ended up using `turf.voronoi` on a `featureCollection` composed by the points previously described, then adding the polygons to a layer with leaflet geoJSON. You can see it [here](https://github.com/blayhem/airmon/blob/master/webui/src/components/Map.jsx), methods `voronoi` and `addVoronoiLayer` (it's far from perfect but it works). Hope this helps @duxk.gh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you to try with [turf.js](http://turfjs.org) instead of d3.js.

Here's the documentation for Voronoi polygons : http://turfjs.org/docs#voronoi

You will get a GeoJSON as result that you can then style as a choropleth map following the Leaflet default example : https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/

Comment: But I need to transform my coordinates set into a FeatureCollection, right? I'm trying to use [polygon](http://turfjs.org/docs/#polygon) in order to do so, but I don't know if it's the correct approach.

Comment: Yes, you need all you points in a featureCollection first. You can do that by looping on the csv rows and create a turf.point for each and then put them all in a featureCollection.

Here's a Fiddle to help you : [https://jsfiddle.net/23t8m6en/19/](https://jsfiddle.net/23t8m6en/19/)